# Que veut dire « avait pu avoir » ?

Tags: grammaire, temps-grammatical

Ma colocataire m'a écrit la phrase suivante dans un email.

> Je ne pense pas que cela te pose un problème vu la discussion qu'on
> **avait pu avoir**, mais si jamais c'est le cas, n'hésites vraiment pas à
> me le dire.

Je ne connais pas la construction **avait pu avoir**.  Moi, j'aurais écrit quelque chose comme "vu la discussion qu'on a eu" ou "vu notre discussion".

Quelles sont les différences sémantiques entre ces trois phrases:

> 1. la discussion qu'on a eu
> 2. notre discussion
> 3. la discussion qu'on avait pu avoir

... et quel est le temps utilisé dans cette dernière ?

Comment: *Avait pu* est le [plus-que-parfait](http://www.conjugaison-verbe.fr/pouvoir.htm) du verbe pouvoir. Son emploi [ici](http://la-conjugaison.nouvelobs.com/regles/conjugaison/plus-que-parfait-de-l-indicatif-36.php) ou [ici](http://www.etudes-litteraires.com/temps-composes.php#2). Dans ton exemple, et sans plus de contexte, j'aurais employé le passé composé (*a pu*) mais 1 et 2 sont possibles et dans le contexte que tu donnes ont le même sens.

Comment: @Laure +1, ça mériterait d'ailleurs une réponse, pas un simple commentaire.

Comment: @AlexisPigeon: je n'ai fait que donner des références facilement trouvables sur internet. Si FL&U était aussi strict que EL&U la question aurait été fermée pour cause de *general reference*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Il s'agit du **plus-que-parfait du verbe *pouvoir*** (*j'avais pu*, *tu avais pu*, etc.) suivi d'un infinitif, ici le verbe *avoir*.

**Exemple :**

> J'avais pu sauvegarder mon fichier avant que l'ordinateur ne plantât.

L'action est au passé : l'ordinateur a planté, donc la situation située encore avant est décrite au plus-que-parfait.

**MAIS**

> Je pouvais sauvegarder le fichier avant que l'ordinateur ne plante, malheureusement j'ai oublié de le faire.

1. Je travaillais sur mon ordinateur et je pouvais sauvegarder.
2. J'ai oublié de sauvegarder alors que je pouvais le faire.
3. L'ordinateur vient de planter, c'est un passé proche donc j'utilise le présent.

***La discussion qu'on avait pu avoir :*** inutile car « que ça te pose un problème » est au présent mais ce n'est pas incorrect. *La discussion qu'on a pu avoir* aurait été plus adapté.

C'est du plus-que-parfait, qui décrit une situation dans le passé plus ancienne qu'une autre situation dans le passé évoquée (ici *le problème que cela te pose*, qui est au présent, c'est pour ça que c'est inadapté).

**On aurait pu dire :** *Je ne pense pas que cela t'a posé un problème vu la discussion qu'on avait pu avoir* (on situe la possible discussion dans un passé antérieur à la situation évoquée, qui elle-même est dans le passé).

**Quant à « avoir pu » au lieu d'« avoir »** (*la discussion qu'on avait pu avoir* au lieu de *la discussion qu'on avait eu*), c'est une histoire de sens : ta collègue indique qu'elle ne se souvient pas exactement de la ou des discussions, mais qu'elle se souvient bien de leur contenu, et qu'elle a pensé, d'après ce que vous vous êtes dit, qu'il n'y avait pas de problème, *même si vous n'en aviez peut-être pas discuté précisément* (vous *avez pu* en discuter).

À part ça, il y a un *s* de trop à « n'hésites pas ». C'est un impératif et la forme correcte est « n'hésite pas ».

Comment: J'ajoute qu'il faut pour le comprendre que ton exemple fasse partie d'une narration. Si la phrase est une information immédiate « j'eus pu » aurait été plus adapté, car l'action est dans ce cas précisément située dans le temps. Il aurait aussi été possible de donner exemple d'utilisation du plus-que-parfait dans un langage de tous les jours (notamment, sans subjonctif imparfait) : « Si seulement j'avais pu sauvegarder mon fichier avant que l'ordinateur ne plante… » (ou « n'ait planté »).

Comment: Merci pour l'édition.